# why does float comparison works without bc in a AND_IF or "&&" command

Tags: bash, shell

The only way I could find out to compare floats in shell is:

```
A=12.3
B=12.2
if [ $(bc <<< "$B <= $A") -eq 1 ]
```

Direct comparison, as far as I know, doesn't happen.

but strangely the following code compares floats without bc:

```
A=13.7
B=13.2

[[ $A > $B ]] && echo "A is greater than B"

[[ $A < $B ]] && echo "A is less than B"
```

This returns:

```
A is greater than B
```

As far as I know && executes the second command only and only if the first command returns with an exit status zero.

However, as suggested by Pixel Chemist in the comments if we attempt to use negative numbers in the second methods, it doesn't work and gives the opposite results.

Can someone please explain how is the second method working without bc.

Comment: Note that if you put a minus in front of both numbers for the second method it still says that `A is greater than B` which is incorrect.

Comment: yes that is accurate it can't compare negative numbers,(if it is comparing at all) can u please suggest an explanation for this behaviour ?

Comment: This doesn't compare numbers at all. From [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs): *When used with `[[`, the `<` and `>` operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.* Try `A=4.7` :)

Comment: `[[` compares patterns, `((` is used to compare numbers, but `bash` does not support floating point.  If you wish to use floating point in a shell use Korn shell (`ksh`), declare the numbers as `float A=13.7` and compare using: `(( A > B )) && echo "A is greater than B"`

Comment: Thanks for your explanations that helped